# Function Parameters Across Different Assemblies

Tags: c#, lambda

Suppose I have a function `DoStuff` that is defined in the assembly A.dll. This function takes a `Func<T>` parameter. I call this function inside of B.dll as `DoStuff(() => ...)`.

Where is the `Func<T>` evaluated? It appears to be inside of B.dll, but I would expect it to be inside of A.dll. What happens if the `Func<T>` requires external references? Am I forced to include them in B.dll? Can I force it to execute inside A.dll?

Comment: What is the requirement, where you are forecd to make such complex implemenation in a real life project, is it possible for you to reveal something more, asking out of curiosity?

Comment: It's more of a design decision. I have a WCF service that I want to make calls against. I defined a wrapper method in a separate assembly that takes a `Func<ServiceClient>` and captures any exceptions to wrap them into a `Response` object I defined. The problem is that I am forced to include extra assemblies wherever I make calls to this method in separate assemblies.

Comment: @bbush perhaps this may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6443433/how-can-i-pass-a-lambda-expression-to-a-wcf-service

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The lambda is compiled into B and executed there.

You can read up more on how it works here: [What are C# lambda's compiled into? A stackframe, an instance of an anonymous type, or?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8993426/what-are-c-sharp-lambdas-compiled-into-a-stackframe-an-instance-of-an-anonymo)

Comment: Great, thank you. Can you think of how I might achieve something like this? I would ideally want the compilation to occur in A. I fiddled with expression trees, which works, technically, but these are severely [limited](http://csharpindepth.com/ViewNote.aspx?NoteID=68).

Comment: @bbush that doesn't make much sense to do that. perhaps you can explain/expand that in a new question that would help.

Comment: Sure thing. I asked [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/34904616/3494973) earlier with no repsonse.

Answer (score 3):

> Where is the Func evaluated?

You are passing the *function definition* from `B` to `A`.  The *compiled* code exists in `B`.  `A` presumably *executes* the function as part of `DoStuff`.

> What happens if the `Func<T>` requires external references?

Then those dependencies will need to be referenced by project B and will need to get included in the final build, which may mean referencing them from the executing project (the WCF service from your comments) as well.

Comment: Great, thank you. Can you think of how I might achieve something like this? I would ideally want the compilation to occur in A. I fiddled with expression trees, which works, technically, but these are severely limited.

Comment: Why do you care where the compiled function is?  What difference does it make?

Comment: It requires extra dependencies depending on where it is compiled. I'd prefer to allow consumers of the A.dll to not require any extra effort.

Comment: `A` should not have to reference the dependencies unless it _directly_ uses them.  Only the project that uses classes/methods from the dependent assembly and the ultimate project (app, web site, service, etc.) should need to reference the dependencies.