# Using EF over WCF

Tags: .net, wcf, entity-framework

How can I expose an Entity Framework `IQueryable<T>` over WCF?

I'm thinking of writing an N-tier application framework and I would like to use Entity Framework and WCF.

I am aware of WCF Data Services, but I do not want REST or HTTP. This is because I want to have bidirectional communication between the clients and the server.

Right now, it will be WinForms/WPF and ASP.NET applications will consume the services.

Comment: Ria or WCF Data Services is the only option.  If you don't want REST you are out of luck

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you may be looking for [WCF RIA Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee707344%28v=vs.91%29.aspx.) or [WCF Data Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/bb931106)

Comment: WCF Data Services is OData which is REST/HTTP.

Comment: So you want a SOAP service that runs using the `NetTcpBinding`?  What don't you like about HTTP?

Comment: I'm looking for  bi-directional communication. I know WCF can do that.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [WCF Data Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/bb931106) / [OData](http://www.odata.org/).  In particular, I think this [video](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg601462) shows an example of what you are trying to do.

Comment: I'm looking for a solution that isn't REST/HTTP.

Answer (score 0):

You could to write the query handling for yourself similar to what the already mentioned Data Services do. Unfortunately you can't serialize LINQ queries, but you can probably serialize LINQ expressions. Check the answer to [Serializing and Deserializing Expression Trees in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/217961/serializing-and-deserializing-expression-trees-in-c).

Another option would be to offer a specific service contract with parameters for every query that you need to make.