# Serializing a LinqtoNh filter/order clause

Tags: linq, nhibernate, rest, linq-to-nhibernate

I've got a REST web service that uses LinqtoNh to query entities and return them as DTO, plain classical stuff. I want the service to apply some filter/order clause on the returned entities, and I'm asking if there is some way of serialize the linqtonh expression in order to send it an the wire without creating some custom strategy. A plus would be not having a NH reference on the client. 
Any suggestion?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/217961/serializing-and-deserializing-expression-trees-in-c-sharp

Comment: @GertArnold agree it is a possible duplicated, but the answer is almost obsolete since the component is no  more mantained

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at WCF Ria Services: It expose a WCF Rest service that supports the LINQ filtering, sorting, paging e grouping. 
Server side the DomainService will create a LINQ query with "Where", "Order*", "Take", "Skip"... 
Avoiding the NH reference it's a great idea, implement your own IQueryable, link it to NHibernate (maybe you want to use an IoC engine to do so) and return it in the exposed queries! You're almost done, most of the LINQ2NH call are standard LINQ extensions method, you would have to write somethign else if you need to use the eager fetching extension method (Fetch*) or other pretty NHibernate-stuff.
As far the client, WCF Ria is initially designed for SL but supports *everything*, they have even JS client called [RIA/JS](http://jeffhandley.com/archive/2011/04/13/RIAJS-jQuery-client-for-WCF-RIA-Services.aspx)