# Expression Trees in String format?

Tags: c#, linq, expression-trees

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Serializing and Deserializing Expression Trees in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/217961/serializing-and-deserializing-expression-trees-in-c-sharp)

I have recently dove into the wild world that is Expression Trees and am curious.

I have been playing with ZeroMQ as well, and it occured to me, I was wondering if I could send expression trees in string format from a client to a server. Is this possible? Expression Trees seem to have the functionality to take an expression, and seems like you should be able to "flatten" and "deflatten" them to/from a string.

Does anybody have any insight on this? If your comments are going to be negative, then please don't comment at all.

**EDIT**
To be clear, as a simple example, if I have a client-server application running, is there a way I can type into the client command prompt the following:

```
(a,b) => a + b
```

and have that value be converted into a binary expression(in an easy way) so that it can be invoked dynamically by the server application?

Comment: Have you looked into Serialization?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [Serializing and Deserializing Expression Trees in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/217961/serializing-and-deserializing-expression-trees-in-c-sharp), you could use the [Expression Tree Serialization](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/exprserialization) project.